# Iframe Not Showing Random Videos

Tags: javascript, iframe

I am working on a script so that it fetches a random video and continuously keeps playing random videos back to back once the previous video is finished playing. It worked when I played the videos as mp4s in the video element, but when I rewrote the script to play them as embedded videos in an iframe, nothing shows up at all.

I just cannot seem to make it work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

```html
<iframe class="frame" src="" width="640" height="360"></iframe>

<script>
  var lastVideo = null;
  var selection = null;
  var player = document.getElementsByClassName("frame")[0]; // Get video element
  var playlist = ["https://www.youtube.com/embed/qXYb8R3_B0k", "https://www.youtube.com/embed/Gi1P6UFTioQ", "https://www.youtube.com/embed/l_pR5obOwss"]; // List of videos
  player.autoplay = true;
  player.addEventListener("ended", getRandomUrl); // Run when video ends

  function getRandomUrl(player) {
    while (selection == lastVideo) { // Repeat until different video is selected
      selection = Math.floor(Math.random() * playlist.length);
    }
    lastVideo = selection; // Remember last video
    player.src = playlist[selection]; // Location of new video

  }

  getRandomUrl(player); // Select first video
  player.play(); // Start video
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would guess that your `eventListener` for "ended" never triggers because a video is never started in the first place.

The solution in this case would be set a random video to the `src` attribute as the default and then the `eventListener` takes care of the rest.

Comment: Hi. Thank you very much for your reply. I did as you suggested, and the video showed up and played, but once the video stopped playing, nothing else happened. It did not continuously choose another random video to play afterwards.

Comment: Hi. I was playing around with the code, and I was able to get it to display a random video on page load. I changed the code from this: player.addEventListener("ended", getRandomUrl); to this: player.addEventListener("ended", getRandomUrl(player));. However, when the video ends, it does not fetch another random video to play.

Comment: Are you able to see the log if you replace the `getRandomUrl` function with a function that only has a `console.log` inside? Maybe the problem is that you are listening for the wrong event.

Comment: I did what you suggested with console.log, and I get the same result. A random video shows up on page load and plays a video, but once it ends, another video does not play. Maybe I will just go back and use the <video> element with the MP4 videos. The script worked flawlessly when I used it with the <video> element. I am just creating a playlist for my nephew to watch like live TV on my personal website because my sister does not allow him on YouTube. He likes watching random videos instead of watching it in sequential order. I will mark this as answered. I appreciate all your help. Thank you.